# Assign weight on multiple suggester fields using Nest client

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a document containing multiple fields for eg - product, product type and brand. I have implemented completion suggesters on all 3 fields but the problem is that I am unable to put a weight on each suggester field. For example if user enters "Car" then suggestion from product should come first and then from product type followed by brands starting with "Car". Any idea how can I add weight using Nest?

Tia